Does "Digital"/binary affect our Being?
I have observed this fact, in todays world, people are ready to accept "bad" regardless of how worse it gets. They don't like it but people kinda accept it as in. "ohh since he/she/it is bad it's expected they'll do whatever", but they are not ready to accept "good" even with the slightest of the the blemishes, they outrightly reject it or vehemently criticize it. The response looks like binary, It has to be perfect if it's good, else it's bad, it seems there aren't any shades of grey anymore. People would be devoted life long but one small mistake and eveything ends, on the other hand one small gesture and people become fan suddenly, it's like people live like either it's this or that with nothing in between. As a consequence Bad/Evil has got society's acceptance whereas Good is denied because people are afraid that they'll lose whatever good they have if they start accepting grey or imperfect good, not 0 but not quite 1 either.
I was kinda thinking is it because we spend a long long time everyday with digital devices (employing binary representations), whose soul is 0 and 1, we have started dealing with this world in terms of 0s and 1s. If it's good it has to be Perfect else it's Bad(can do whatever it's accepted.).
Is it even possible?! Are there any studies done on topics like these?!
[Edit]
Guys, this question got 4 close votes, I am just wondering, even in Philosophy such questions are not allowed?! Why is this tendency to tie down EVERYTHING to "Defined". This question, just by itself, even as the remotest possibiity, is profound in it's implications. AND I FIRMLY BELIEVE THIS IS TRUE, I just need to find way to tell this.
If everything alive/moving in a sense in these devices is nothing but 0 and 1, HOW IS IT POSSIBLE THAT IT DOESN'T HAVE ANY EFFECT. It just defies Logic. See in this Nature, Mind has a way of interacting with Creation, Heart has a way of Interacting with Nature, Ego has a way of interacting Nature(meaning everything), similarly your Consciousness has a way of Interacting with Nature, and at the level of Consciousness THE ONLY WAY OF INTERACTING/INTERACTION IS BY BEING IT. So if you really engaged with a digital machine your consciousness is being it, if you are really engaged/absorbed, subconsciously the difference between you and the Machine vanishes, that machine becomes Extension of You. So does it become an extension Physically?! No it doesn't, it is a separate physical device, but Extension it does become, material sciences may call it "extension of cognitive Self" or whatever, Spirituality calls it extension of Consciousness.
I hope you believe in Existence Of Consciousness, if you do, then please also believe that the Consciousness has a way of Interacting with the Universe and it's by Being It.
Hence Digital Does affect you because you were digital when you were engrossed with a Digital Device.

Feel free to revert but I guess binary matches more how you use the word than digital

@haxor789 yes you are correct, actually it's binary but since digital is binary I guess it's alright, also binary wouldn't have emphasized use of devices. Digital makes it clear that the question is regarding our interaction with devices.

Speaking as an electrical engineer, the average person doesn't know a thing about binary logic. They've been introduced to the concept of ones and zeros, but it doesn't impact their life in the slightest. The assertion that digitalization is driving our behavior to no longer compromise would be, IMO, so hard to prove that I'm comfortable claiming it's entirely false. In support of my belief is the research suggesting that the ubiquitous violence experienced by today's movie-going/game-playing youth won't result in a generation of psychopathic killers.

@JBH "movie-going/game-playing youth won't result in a generation of psychopathic killers." << This is EXACTLY the kind of thing I am talking about. "movie-going/game-playing" may result in many types of people in between but we took it to the extreme i.e psychopathic killers, which is like 0 in binary. It's like either the person is going to be a perfect gentleman(1) or psychopathic killer(0). Also I don't think "knowing" binary is required to be affected by it, in this context.

One cannot be changed by something that cannot be experienced.

Does "experienced" have to be conscious or can it be subconscious as well?!

"If everything alive/moving in a sense in these devices is nothing but 0 and 1, HOW IS IT POSSIBLE THAT IT DOESN'T HAVE ANY EFFECT." - one, the physical world is much more complex than a sequence of binary numbers (some physical numbers are irrational and not expressible as a finite sequence of digits), and two, two things being made of the same stuff wouldn't necessarily imply that they affect each other. Interacting with a machine is just our eyes seeing the photons that the screen emits and our conscious brains responding with taps of a finger, nothing more.

Hey @controlgroup Biological Energy example Consciousness, Feelings etc. you know are things that aren't physical or "material" and in my opinion their interaction with materials isn't similar to interaction between materials and energies. From The design or cars to dance styles, everything earlier was curvy, smooth flowing, continuous, now a days cars have designs that have edges, it's not smooth, dances are in fits and starts and songs are more "words" these days rather than continuous melodies, discreet, discontinuous. Why have humans started liking such designs and dances?!@!!!

I think you're ignoring a lot of designs and music and dances, then. For the record: many early architecture styles, and many modern ones before the computing era, used plenty of hard right angles (brutalist architecture predates computing and is one of my favorite styles). As for songs and designs... you seem to be ignoring Tesla, Apple, 100% of all ambient music artists, etc. who specifically design things to be smooth. There's some selection bias at play here.

@controlgroup I agree maybe there is some bias but "rise in popularity" of various things that have some common characteristics cannot be refuted. I didn't do a thorough study or anything of the matter but it's more of a general observation...

Perhaps a study is necessary, because nobody else can see the pattern you’re describing. I’m virtually certain that there’ll be no discernible change over time in whatever values you can quantify.

Hey @controlgroup I am actually a researcher in Cognitive Instruments. I have for more than 1.5 Decade now I am trying to understand these things including Consciousness for quite some time now. "Knowing by being it" is a time tested, obvious fact of Everyday Life. You'll not know what a Dad is untill and unless you become one. You may know "facts" about "Dad" or "Being Dad" but when you become one, you know it's not quite the same, all of those facts and "understandings" combined and still amazingly no matter how "intelligent" you are you cannot describe "Dad" to me, all you can give me are..

Hey @controlgroup "facts" and "information" about "dad" or "being dad" BUT YOU CANNOT Describe DAD. This "knowing" and "not being able to describe" shows that there is a level of knowing which goes beyond Mind. Mind knows by observing facts and figures and will confidently say "I know" about dad or being dad, heart knows by feeling, but there is a level that goes beyond these and if that "understandng" is not by reading facts and figures, or feeling (as in empathy) then the only thing remains is "being it". So consciousness knows it by being it. You become digital/binary....

I mean, even if that’s true, so? Theoretically I was expressible as binary before (the approximate state of all my neurons encoded as numbers). What does “becoming binary” even mean in this definition? That has become increasingly unclear.

No, I don't think we're becoming more "binary" because of our daily interaction with digital stuff, although as they say in Italy, se non è vero, è ben trovato. I mean, it's a funny thought, attractive but probably not true.
Are people more "binary" now than they were in the past? I don't think so, and can't think of any possible evidence for that.

I added some more content to the question, please have a look, you may change your opinion :). Thanks...

@AshishShukla People didn't become more vaporous during the steam engine era, did they?

physical effects are one thing and effects on psyche are another thing.

If we had used ternary, we wouldn't become more... ternary, whatever that means. The fact that we used binary is just because it was easy. If anything there are more people now breaking out of binary norms than before.

@controlgroup Good point.


we spend a long long time everyday with digital devices (employing binary representations), whose soul is 0 and 1, we have started dealing with this world in terms of 0s and 1s.

No, the world is not "made of" 0s and 1s.
See Luciano Floridi, Against digital ontology(Synthese, 2009):

The paper argues that digital ontology (the ultimate nature of reality is digital, and the universe is a computational system equivalent to a Turing Machine) should be carefully distinguished from informational ontology (the ultimate nature of reality is structural), in order to abandon the former and retain only the latter as a promising line of research.

But for the opposite view, see Wolfram's computational universe hypothesis: "computation is ultimately what’s underneath everything in our universe".

I added some more content to the question, please have a look, you may change your opinion :). Thanks...
